# BLDC motor equations

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, equation

I've read [this](http://www.olliw.eu/2013/brushless-gimbal-direct-drive/) article about driving gimbal motors.

I have some questions about these equations:

[image]

1. I don't understand what "ψ" and "Lω" means and generally i don't understand how to calculate the equation. Can someone explain this to me?

[image]

2. In this equation i don't understand what how to calculate d/dt, and i don't understand what "ψ" and "Rω" is.

Comment: The article says this *The following motor model can be found in any introductory text on 3-phase motors* directly above the equations so, have you tried to find such an article and, do you understand matrix math? If either answer is no then you shouldn't be asking this question here because it means you haven't done sufficient research on your own.

Comment: Search for "James Mevey thesis" and you'll find a pretty good introductory text. But you'll have to go even more basic if you really haven't seen differential calculus like d/dt before.